# Convert lowercase to uppercase using ASCII

Tags: c, ascii, uppercase, lowercase

I am trying to convert all lowercase to uppercase letter, using the ASCII table! It is very easy to deal and i have figured out the code. Problem is, that if there is a space between the words, then the program will only change the first word and after the space it will not print anything.

Example
Word: Andreas Gives: ANDREAS
Word: TeSt123Ha Gives: TEST123HA
BUT!!!
Word: Hello 45 Gives: HELLO
after the space it prints nothing!

I know that the space in ASCII table is equal to 32, and in my code i tell the program that if the current code that you are reading is not between 97 and 122, then don't perform any changes!

But it is still not working!

```C
char currentletter;
int i;

for (i=0; i<49; i++)    
{
    currentletter = str[i];

    if ((currentletter > 96) && (currentletter < 123))
    {
        char newletter;
        newletter = currentletter - 32;
        str[i] = newletter;
    }
    else
    {
        str[i] = currentletter;
    }
}
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Comment: You don't show how `str` is initialized - I'll bet the words after the space aren't even in there (is `str` initialized with `argv[1]`?) What happens if you do `printf("%s\n", str);` *before* the case conversion code?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Good point. `scanf("%s", str)` is another contender for single-word input.

Comment: Your `else` branch is not the source of the problem but still completely redundant.

Comment: The 32 in your program is 'a'-'A'. In addition to ASCII, this will probably work with the character set/encoding/code page you are actually using. Maybe Windows-1252 or Unicode/UTF-8? Use `locale` (Linux) or `chcp` (Windows) to check. Of course, those characters sets have more letters that you aren't accounting for.

Comment: @Tom: in Windows-1252 and in UTF8 this code is still valid, since the codes for 32 up to 126 are all the same. But perhaps you were thinking of EBCDIC.

Comment: @Jongware My points are 1) yes, this algorithm works for the [ISO basic Latin alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) in character set encodings that are likely being used and 2) _ASCII is not what is likely being used._

Answer (score 13, accepted):

flipping the 5th lowest bit should help.

> Each lowercase letter is 32 + uppercase equivalent. This means simply flipping the bit at position 5 (counting from least significant bit at position 0) inverts the case of a letter.
>   https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs107/lab1/practice.html

```
char *str;
int str_size = sizeof(str);

for(int i=0; i<str_size;i++){
   if((str[i]>96) && (str[i]<123)) str[i] ^=0x20;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have [mentioned in one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821178/convert-lowercase-to-uppercase-using-ascii/25821868#comment40394804_25821340) that you use `scanf("%s", str);` to get the string. The problem is that `%s` will stop scanning once it finds a whitespace character. In your case, it stops scanning when it sees the space character.

Use `fgets()` if you want to scan one whole line:

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

Once thing to note here is that `fgets` will scan in the newline character into the string as well.

---

Your code can be simplified to:

```
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) // Loop until the NUL-terminator
{
    if ((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z')) // If the current character is a lowercase alphabet
        str[i] = str[i] - ('a' - 'A');      // See the ASCII table to understand this:
                                            // http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif
}

printf("%s\n", str);
```

Or a more easier way would be to use `tolower` from `ctype.h`:

```
#include <ctype.h>

for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) // Loop until the NUL-terminator
{
    str[i] = tolower(str[i]); // Convert each character to lowercase (It does nothing if the character is not an alphabet)
}

printf("%s\n", str);
```

Answer (score -1):

I gave it a try using STL and a Lambda just for fun:

```
string input = "";
getline(cin, input);
transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), [](char c) { return (c > 96 && c < 123) ? c ^= 0x20 : c; });
copy(input.begin(), input.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
```

I compiled and tested with c++ 17 in Visual Studio 2019,
and did not perform exhaustive testing!

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:c] not [tag:c++]